# how to import a data model from Excel

Tags: sql-server-2008, csv

I was given an excel (csv) sheet containing a database metadata.
I'm asking if there's a simple way to import the csv and create the tables from there?

Data is not part of this question.  the csv looks like this:

```
logical_table_name, physical_table_name, logical_column_name, physcial_column_name, data_type, data_length
```

There's about 2000 rows of metadata.  I'm hoping I don't have to manually create the tables.  Thanks.

Comment: what did a google search bring up? "sql server import from excel"

Comment: four google pages of "how to import data"

Comment: I went through four pages of hits....thanks.

Comment: I'd try 'schema import' not just import.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any direct import or creation. However, if I had to do this and I couldn't find one, I would import the excel file into a staging table (just a direct data import). I'd make add a unique auto ID column to staging table to keep the rows in order.

Then I would use some queries to build table and column creation commands from the raw data. Unless this was something I was setting up to do a lot, I would keep it dead simple, not try and get fancy. Build individual add column commands for each column. Build a create Table command for the first row for each table. Sort them all by the order id, tables before columns. Then you should be able to just copy the script column, check the commands, and go.